# Inheritance in class object not work and showing type error

Tags: python, oop, debugging, typeerror

```
class BankAccount:
  def __init__(self):
    self.balance=0
  
  def withdraw(self,amount):
    self.balance-=amount
    return self.balance

  def deposit(self,amount):
    self.balance=amount+self.balance
    return self.balance
```

```
class MinimumBalanceAccount(BankAccount):
    def __init__(self, minimum_balance):
      BankAccount.__init__(self)
      self.minimum_balance = minimum_balance
      
    def withdraw(self, amount):
      if (self.balance - amount) < (self.minimum_balance):
        print('Sorry, minimum balance must be maintained.')
      else:
        BankAccount.withdraw(self, amount)
```

```
a=BankAccount()
a.balance
a.deposit(10)
```

```
aa=MinimumBalanceAccount(a)
aa.withdraw(1)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-179-6160646c7f5f> in <module>()
      1 aa=MinimumBalanceAccount(a)
----> 2 aa.withdraw(1)

<ipython-input-168-6b59b3de5e45> in withdraw(self, amount)
      5 
      6     def withdraw(self, amount):
----> 7       if (self.balance - amount) < (self.minimum_balance):
      8         print('Sorry, minimum balance must be maintained.')
      9       else:

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'BankAccount'
```

I'm revising the basics of OOP with this piece of code.Anyone can help me clear the error. I'm lost what I'm doing wrong.Why is there a type error?

Comment: `MinimumBalanceAccount(a)` — You're passing an instance of `BankAccount` as the value for `minimum_balance`…!? That should probably be a number instead?!

Comment: @deceze I created an object of Bankaccount and passed that into MinimumBalanceAccount which already has the value balance as 0..okey...I think I got the point.If I had not written created self.minimum_balance  then it would have worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

You have your base class `BankAccount` which looks fine. You could also let the initializer take a balance and set the default value to 0.

```py
class BankAccount:
  def __init__(self, balance=0):
    self.balance = balance
  
  def withdraw(self, amount):
    self.balance -= amount
    return self.balance

  def deposit(self, amount):
    self.balance += amount
    return self.balance
```

There are some issues in your subclass. First, you attempt to initialize it with the class blueprint itself instead of its instance. You can do this by calling the `__init__()` method of the superclass, which will give you access to all its attributes and methods.

```py
class MinimumBalanceAccount(BankAccount):
    def __init__(self, minimum_balance):
      super().__init__()
      self.minimum_balance = minimum_balance
```

You decide to override the inherited `withdraw()` method but try to retain some of its original functionality. Unfortunately, you can't have it both ways, so you will need to re-add that functionality to your overriden method. Note that you can now access balance from the superclass using `self.balance`.

```py
def withdraw(self, amount):
      difference = self.balance - amount
      if difference < self.minimum_balance:
        print('Sorry, minimum balance must be maintained.')
      else:
        self.balance = difference
      return self.balance
```

With the implementation of the class outlined as above, the output of your test will then result in the following:

```py
a = MinimumBalanceAccount(0)
a.balance  # -> 0 (by default)
a.deposit(10)  # -> 10
a.withdraw(5)  # -> 5
```

**Edit:**

Here is an implementation of the subclass which allows you to also adjust the balance in the superclass. This way, you never actually have to manually instantiate `BankAccount` anywhere else in your code:

```py
class MinimumBalanceAccount(BankAccount):
    def __init__(self, balance, minimum_balance):
      super().__init__(balance)
      self.minimum_balance = minimum_balance
      
    def withdraw(self, amount):
      difference = self.balance - amount
      if difference < self.minimum_balance:
        print('Sorry, minimum balance must be maintained.')
      else:
        self.balance = difference
      return self.balance
```

The output then as follows:

```py
a = MinimumBalanceAccount(balance=100, minimum_balance=0)
a.balance  # -> 100
a.deposit(10)  # -> 110
a.withdraw(5)  # -> 105
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for this explanation.As I am passing bank account in to the minimum account one, shouldn't the Minimumaccount inherit the values in the class bank account.So, why can't/ how can I pass the value of bankaccount into the MinimumBalanceaccount.
a=BankAccount will create a.balance as zero.
I want to use this for my MinimumBalanceaccount.

Comment: ```
class MinimumBalanceAccount(BankAccount):
    def __init__(self,n):
      BankAccount.__init__(self)
      self.minimum_balance = 0
      
`````

Comment: How can I inherit the properties of class Bankaccount ?

Comment: I edited the answer to show how you can add the balance attribute to the class. You inherit all properties of the superclass by calling `super.__init__()` in the initializer of the subclass. In your example, you are trying to call a generic class blueprint which happens to be the same type as the superclass, but this is not explicitly coupled and therefore purely coincidental.